# What are the ways to return a result set from a trigger?

Tags: sql, resultset, sql-server-2016, database-trigger

My company is about to update our SQL server to 2016. Therefore I am looking through all our triggers (there's a lot!) locating the ones, which return result sets.

So far I have checked for "select" (not part of insert, delete, update and variable assignment), "exec" of stored procedures, "return", and "fetch", which doesn't "fetch into @someVar".

What are the other SQL statements, which can result in a trigger returning a result set?

Comment: What version are you upgrading *from*? SQL Server 2008 introduced `output` clauses.

Comment: Why not run your test suite with "disallow results from triggers"?
 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/disallow-results-from-triggers-server-configuration-option)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: We are using 2012 R2. Thanks, I'll look into that one :)